# Relation of Hodge dual to antisymmetric part of the

Tags: mathematical-physics, tensors, symmetry

I have a question in reaction to an article by M. Born and L. Infeld (cf. [1]) concerning the relation between the hodge dual of the electromagnetic tensor and the antisymmetrization of its derivative.

Basically, they state the following equivalence:
$$
\partial_{[\nu} f_{\rho\sigma]} = 0
\iff
\partial_{\nu} (\sqrt{-g} \star f^{\mu\nu}) = 0
$$
where $f_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$, $\star f^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{-g}} \epsilon^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu} f_{\rho\sigma}$ and $g$ is the determinant of the metric (on a 4-dimensional manifold with signature $(+,-,-,-)$).  Has anybody any idea where this equivalence comes from?  I have come to the following identities:
$$
\partial_\nu (\sqrt{-g} \star f^{\mu\nu}) = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \partial_\nu f_{\rho\sigma},\\
\partial_{[i_1} f_{i_2 i_3]} = \frac{1}{3!} \epsilon^{j_1 j_2 j_3}_{i_1 i_2 i_3} \partial_{j_1} f_{j_2 j_3},
$$
but I don't see how the $\mu$ in the first expression drops out.

As a side note, in the article it is frequently assumed that $\partial_\mu \sqrt{-g} = 0$.  Was it a convention that partial derivatives are to be considered covariant?

Cheers,
Eric

[1] http://www.jstor.org/stable/2935568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:
$$
\partial_\nu (\sqrt{-g} \star f^{\mu\nu}) = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \partial_\nu f_{\rho\sigma},
$$

that you found, is exactly what you are trying to prove. The non-zero components of that expressions are:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \partial_{[\nu} f_{\rho\sigma]},
$$

where $\mu$ is a free index. The expression is zero for every $\mu$ if and only if:
$$
\partial_{[\nu} f_{\rho\sigma]}=0.
$$